# Php x-debug with Atom Not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, xdebug, atom-editor, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to configure php x-debug with Atom. I am using OS High Sierra. Installed x-debug and can see in php info. Also installed php debug package in atom. conf.cson has:

```
  "php-debug":
PathMaps: [
  "remotepath;localpath"
  "localhost/opa;/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/OPA"
]
ServerAddress: "127.0.0.1"
ServerPort: 9000
currentConsoleHeight: "292px"
currentPanelMode: "side"
currentPanelWidth: "570px"
```

And in Php.ini

```
zend_extension = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

I can see listening at 127.0.0.1:9000 in Atom but nothing happens when I load website. Breakpoint never get any hit. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

My Php info for x-debug is:

[image: First Part]

[image: Second Part]

Comment: 1) Where is the rest of xdebug `phpinfo()` section? 2) What xdebug has to say?

Comment: Added remaining part of phpinfo()

Comment: Xdebug config is OK (nothing obvious wrong) .. but what about #2 -- xdebug log -- it should tell what happens when xdebug tries to connect and  where. So far the most common error would be that you also have php-fpm installed on your Mac .. and xdebug connects there (as they both use the same TCP 9000 port... If you do not have it installed (or you have changed the default port for it) .. then maybe it's connects to Atom .. but there are path mapping issues? The log should tell the general picture ... so you can decide what way to dig further.

Comment: Lets assume that it's not php-fpm issue (which you may not have since you are using XAMPP) and it's path mappings (I'm judging based on the info you have provided and I do not like the `remotepath` value -- `localhost/opa`). AFAIK it has to be **full** actual physical path on remote system and not some URL. Since it's all local -- you either have to put the same path for local and remote... or not provide any at all. Unless you have symbolic links in the path ... then you have to provide final/resolved path (as that's what xdebug/PHP uses).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, had this in the log file:

```
[33824] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[33824] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[33824] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[33824] I: Remote address found, connecting to [::1]:9000.
[33824] W: Creating socket for '[::1]:9000', getaddrinfo: Undefined error: 0.
[33824] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

you need to switch the xdebug.remote_connect_back to 0:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

also to get the log i posted above you can add this: (adjust you path accordingly)

```
xdebug.remote_log=/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/xdebug.log
```

So my full setup in php.ini looks like this:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_log=/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/xdebug.log
```